# Pass linq anonymous object to function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this Linq query on my Controller which will give me an object in a List and I need to pass this object to a function, that is in another class, which will consume it.

This is my Linq query:

```
var cursos = (from c in db.Curso
              join cc in db.CursoCategoria on c.cursoCategoriaId equals cc.ID
              where c.ativo == 1 && c.destaque == 1
              select new { ID        = c.ID,
                           nome      = c.nome,
                           imgAbre   = c.imagemAbre,
                           imgFecha  = c.imagemEfeito,
                           cURL      = c.URL,
                           ccURL     = cc.URL,
                           cCor      = cc.cor}).Take(10).ToList();
```

This is how I call the function:

```
var objHelper = new HelperController();
siteVM.lstCursosWall = Json(objHelper.MontaWallCurso());
```

This is my function in HelperController, this class is also a Controller, I have it as this because I have several helper functions and ajax methods for the project:

```
public string MontaWallCurso()
{
     //TODO STUFF       
}
```

So, how can I pass this object if I don't have a type?

Note: I'm using a DAL model that I create from my database using EF, don't know if this is useful.

**EDIT**

So I change my method and created a class to populate and transfer the data, but now I'm having problems passing the linq result to the object.

```
var siteVM  = new SiteViewModel();
var cursos  = new List<CursoWall>();
var lCursos = (from c in db.Curso
               join cc in db.CursoCategoria on c.cursoCategoriaId equals cc.ID
               where c.ativo == 1 && c.destaque == 1
               select new { ID        = c.ID,
                            nome      = c.nome,
                            imgAbre   = c.imagemAbre,
                            imgFecha  = c.imagemEfeito,
                            cURL      = c.URL,
                            ccURL     = cc.URL,
                            cCor      = cc.cor}).Take(10).ToList();

cursos.AddRange(lCursos);
```

The class:

```
public class CursoWall
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string imgAbre { get; set; }
    public string imgFecha { get; set; }
    public string cURL { get; set; }
    public string ccURL { get; set; }
    public string cCor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `select new {...` do `select new CursoWall() {...`

Comment: also you can get rid of the lCursos variable and the AddRange and just assign directly since you are making a new List<CursoWall>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot**. You need to define a simple 'Poco' type for DTO for data transfer in this case.

http://rlacovara.blogspot.nl/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html

Comment: Ok, i created the class as he mentioned but now i can't find a way to pass the linq to it

I get a conversion problem error ! It's on the EDIT part

Comment: @Terkhos - see my comment on the main question

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to sacrifice type safety, you could use C#'s dynamic support.

```
public string MontaWallCurso(IList<dynamic> cursos) {
    // use dynamic properties or something that takes dynamic arguments
    foreach( dynamic curso in cursos ) {
        curso.SomePropertyYouAreSureExists = 1;
        curso.SomeMethodYouAreSureExists();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are willing to sacrifice type safety and deal with the trouble, you could use reflection. There are some cases where you can do this indirectly, e.g. a JSON converter or other reflection-reliant library code.

```
public string MontaWallCurso(IList<object> cursos) {
    // use reflection or something that uses reflection itself
    foreach( object curso in cursos ) {
        Type cursoType = curso.GetType();
        cursoType.GetProperty("SomePropertyYouAreSureExists").SetValue( curso, 1 );
        cursoType.GetProperty("SomeMethodYouAreSureExists").Invoke( curso, null );
    }
}
```

To clarify, of these approaches, the only one that I would likely recommend is the library-based reflection one if it's applicable.

Comment: Got an error calling the function: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>`

Comment: I apologize; I only tested with array arguments. Using `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()` would avoid the issue in your case.

Comment: My previous comment was in reference to the pre-edit version of your code.

Comment: No problem but i need it to be a List because of how i consume it but thanks anyway.